# how to limit amount my command spam (discord.py)

Tags: command, discord.py, limit

I want to limit the amount that can be entered as an argument for the `spam` command. How can I do this? This is the code I'm working with:

```py
@client.command()
async def spam(ctx, message=None,* ,amount : int):
  for _ in range(amount):
    await ctx.send(message)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple if-statement will do it. Also, your arguments for the command are not ordered properly. The following code is more ideal. Try this out and modify the spam limit number accordingly:

```py
@client.command()
async def spam(ctx, amount : int, *, message=None):
    limit = 5
    if amount > limit:
        await ctx.send("exceeds spam limit")
        return
    else:
        for _ in range(amount): 
            await ctx.send(message)
```

To run this, you will have to do `spam <amount> <message>`. For example, `!spam 4 hello this is a spam`.

Answer (score 0):

from discord.ext import commands

## Custom check to validate the amount argument

def is_valid_spam_amount(amount):
return 1 <= amount <= 10  # Set the desired range for the amount (1 to 10 in this example)

```
@client.command()
async def spam(ctx, message=None, *, amount: int):
    if is_valid_spam_amount(amount):
        for _ in range(amount):
            await ctx.send(message)
    else:
        await ctx.send("Invalid amount. Please provide a value between 1 and 10.")
```